# Hide second drop down box using css only-not working

Tags: html, css

I want to hide the second drop down box in the following code using css only.

```css
.dt select:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="dt">
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select> 
  <b>:</b>
  <select> <!--want to hide this select box-->
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
  </select> 
  <b>:</b>
  <select>
    <option>x</option>
    <option>y</option>
    <option>z</option>
  </select> 
</span>
```

But this is not working..How can I do this?

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/aro5ye6r/)

Answer (score 2):

Just change the `2` to `3` and it works:

```
.dt select:nth-child(3) {
    display:none;
}
```

[Apparently](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), the first element is not at the index 0, but 1.

Answer (score 1):

`.dt select:nth-child(2)` will apply only if the `select` element happens to be the second element in `.dt`. In this case a `b` is the second element. What you need to use is `nth-of-type` which will get the second `select` element in `.dt`.

```css
.dt select:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="dt">
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select> 
    <b>:</b>
     <select> <!--want to hide this select box-->
        <option>a</option>
        <option>b</option>
        <option>c</option>
    </select> 
     <b>:</b>
     <select>
        <option>x</option>
        <option>y</option>
        <option>z</option>
    </select> 
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aro5ye6r/1/)**

```
p:nth-child(2) {
    display:none;
}
p {
    float:left;
}
```

CSS:

```
<span class="dt">
    <p><select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select> 
        <b>:</b></p><p>
     <select>
        <option>a</option>
        <option>b</option>
        <option>c</option>
    </select> 
    <b>:</b></p><p>
     <select>
        <option>x</option>
        <option>y</option>
        <option>z</option>
    </select> </p>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.dt select:nth-child(3) option {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<span class="dt">
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select> 
    <b>:</b>
     <select>
        <option>a</option>
        <option>b</option>
        <option>c</option>
    </select> 
     <b>:</b>
     <select>
        <option>x</option>
        <option>y</option>
        <option>z</option>
    </select> 
</span>
```

Comment: This isn't what the OP wants, they want the second `select` hidden not the `option`s it contains.